# Opening multiple terminal with remote access

Tags: linux, unix, remote-desktop, remote-access

I am using remotely logged in to my work server through SSH. I have to work on terminal and it will be helpful if I can pull up multiple terminal to access multiple directories and files. How can I do that? I am a beginner. So, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

screen is a great tool for this.

```
screen -m
```

will open a daemonized screen window and you can detach it to return to your primary shell with

Ctrl+A , then press D

To resume the screen use

```
screen -r
```

You can create multiple screens with names and resume them individually. Checkout the manpages for more info

Comment: This works but scrren pops up a new terminal on top of existing one. So, I can't simultaneously work on both of them. Is there any way to detach it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "screen" on you server to open more shell session in a "dedicated" environment so you can even disconnect from the server without loosing your shells (in case of idle, for example).

see http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/